# Excel - Create Marlett checkboxes Group Functionality

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating checkbox functionality using Excel cells. I've been working on VBA code that:

1. Allows double-click functionality on a cell which enters (or removes) a Marlett check/ tick represented with an "a" in the cell value. I.e., by double-clicking the cell "a" is either entered or removed.
2. The double-click functionality works on a group of cells B1:B10, where:
3. Double-clicking cell B1 will toggle the "a" in both cell B1 and cells B2:B10 collectively, and
4. Double-clicking on any cell B2:B10 will individually toggle between entering and removing "a" in that particular cell.

You could think of B1 being the 'master' controller (eventually I would like this cell to represent a category heading) and B2:B10 to be items within the category that could be individually selected or deselected.
Here is the working code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:B10")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        If Target.Value = "a" Then
            Target.Value = vbNullString
        Else
            Target.Value = "a"
            Target.Font.Name = "Marlett"
        End If
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        If Me.Range("B1").Value = "a" Then
            Me.Range("B1").Value = vbNullString
            Me.Range("B2:B10").Value = vbNullString
        Else
            Me.Range("B1").Value = "a"
            Me.Range("B2:B10").Value = "a"
            Me.Range("B2:B10").Font.Name = "Marlett"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This works fine for 1 group of rows (B1:B10), but I want to extend this code to multiple groups of rows, where there is 1 'master' controlling row within the group, but the individual rows within the group can also be individually controlled. So for example, in an new additional group, B11:B20, the B11 cell would toggle the "a" in both cell B11 and cells B12:B20 collectively, and B12:B20 could individually toggle between entering and removing "a" in each particular cell. And this functionality could repeat for more additional groups if they are added (e.g., B21:28, B29:35, etc and so on). Just for clarity - Each group would not impact on the functionality of any other group.

I'm fairly new to coding so I'm stumped and would appreciate any solutions offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Subroutine that handles one group.

```
Sub HandleCheckboxRange(target As Range, masterCell As Range, groupRange As Range)
    Const checked = "a"

    If Intersect(target, groupRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim newValue As String
    newValue = IIf(target = checked, vbNullString, checked)
    
    If Not Intersect(target, masterCell) Is Nothing Then
        ' Master cell was clicked: Set the whole range
        groupRange.Value = newValue
        groupRange.Font.Name = "Marlett"
    Else
        ' Any other cell of range was clicked: Set only this cell
        target.Value = newValue
        target.Font.Name = "Marlett"
    End If
End Sub
```

The routine expects 3 parameter: The first is the cell that was clicked (`target`), the second defines the master cell for a group, the third the range for the complete group (including the master cell).

In the DoubleClick-Event, call this subroutine for every group you want to handle:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    HandleCheckboxRange target, Range("B1"), Range("B1:B10")
    HandleCheckboxRange target, Range("B11"), Range("B11:B20")
    HandleCheckboxRange target, Range("B21"), Range("B21:B28")
    ' (and so on)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That is pretty close! The only thing that doesn't seem to work is "deselecting" i.e. removing the "a" from the individual checkboxes. You can toggle the "a" using the master cell in each group. You can toggle the "a" on in the individual cells within the group, but then toggling off doesn't' seem to work for me.

Comment: That's strange - it works for me and I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Stupid me did a mistake when setting `newValue`. I have updated the code, the line needs to be `newValue = IIf(target = checked, vbNullString, checked)`

Comment: That works nicely, thanks!